# AWS how to retrieve custom ciphers for a load balancer

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, elastic-load-balancer

I am new to aws probably thats why I am missing something very obvious would really appreciate if someone could help me on this. I am trying to get all the custom ciphers for one of my load balancer and check that against the desired ciphers that I will have in my yaml file.

I am using python for this and have checked boto library and their is no direct way to get custom cipher for a load balancer. I have a TestCipherPolicy load balancer below is the screenshot for the same.

[image]

This load balancer has some custom ciphers which is under listener tab. When I click on change I can see all the ciphers enabled for that load balancer screen shot below -

[image]

What would be the best way read/get all the ciphers enabled for this load balancer programmatically. Agan this is for Custom security policy not for Predefined Security Policy.

Would really appreciate any help or direction on this. Please do not hesitate if any clarification is required.

Comment: Have you tried http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_ssl_policies?

Comment: Thanks Luke for your help. I did try that but describe_ssl_policies() works for Predefined Security Policy not for Custom Security Policy. Because Custom Security Policy wont be having any name assigned to it. If somehow a name was assigned to that custom policy we could easily use describe_ssl_policies() to get all the ciphers associated with that load balancer. I also tried not giving any name when calling describe_ssl_policies() still it didn't work :(